# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE importing error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, data-import

I am working currently on a Java Project

I have a 2D MAP made with char's (in a text file ) :
 **THE SPACE MISSING IS IN PURPOSE JUST TO MAKE THE MAP LOOKING RIGHT**

```
*___________________________*;
|............................|;
|............................|;
|............................|;
|............................|;
*___*.*_*____________*_*.*___*;
|E..*.|.OOO.O.O.O.OOO..|.*..E|;
|**...|.OO...O..O.OOO..*...**|;
|**...*.OOO.O.O.O.O.O..|...**|;
|.....|................|.....|;
*_____*................|.....*;
|.....|................|.....|;
|.J...|................|.....|;
|_____*________________*_____|;
|E....................M......|;
*;___________________________*;
```

I am using 
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" to insert this end in my table :

**table code :**

```
 CREATE TABLE `lorann`.`Niveau` 
( `ID_Niveau` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `contenu` text(300)
 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Niveau`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "import":

```
"C:/Utilisateurs/Moham/desktop/Bureau/Cesi/Ressources/lvl.txt"
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' ENCLOSED BY ';' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

But my problem here is why it return me : 
[IMAGE OF WHAT IT RETURN TO ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z9bb.png)

THE ID is 0 it means it dosent increment at all ? What is the problem i tried to change the syntax and the format of the map i am trying to import sadly , it dont work

**Thanks for the help**

Comment: why have you enclosed by ';'? if you want the entire text content i would enclose with " and make sure you have wrapped your content in "content" quotes

Comment: Yes , because i want to do it like inlines that's why i enclosed with ';' but i will fix it and do it with " after this , may i ask you what you mean by "content in quotes " ?

Answer (score 0):

Comments are too small to add this so put suggestion here. Try This

Wrap your content in quotes:

```
"*___________________________*;
|............................|;
|............................|;
|............................|;
|............................|;
*___*.*_*____________*_*.*___*;
|E..*.|.OOO.O.O.O.OOO..|.*..E|;
|**...|.OO...O..O.OOO..*...**|;
|**...*.OOO.O.O.O.O.O..|...**|;
|.....|................|.....|;
*_____*................|.....*;
|.....|................|.....|;
|.J...|................|.....|;
|_____*________________*_____|;
|E....................M......|;
*;___________________________*;"
```

then change your load data command to :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Utilisateurs/Moham/desktop/Bureau/Cesi/Ressources/lvl.txt"
INTO TABLE `lorann`.`Niveau` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    (contenu)
```

Basically saying fields are seperated by a comma (in this case redundant as you are only importing one field...the id is auto increment)

Content is contained in quotes `""`. In theory should allow you to have line breaks and obscure `;` type characters in the content

Then lastly saying insert into `contenu` field only as id will auto generate.

Might not be able to use `LINES TERMINATED BY` `\n` in your case as rows do go over multiple lines. Im hoping the `ENCLOSED BY` will tell the mysql parser to ignore \n inside the quotes `"`. if that doesn't work maybe use semi colon or something as a `LINE TERMINATED BY`